# Trying to get links from an RSS feed with Syndicationitem

Tags: c#

I am trying to get links from an rss feed like so:

```
<item>
<title>
Mothers CAN wear the same clothes as their daughters
</title>
<link>
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-4408430/Mothers-wear-clothes-daughters.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490
</link>
<description>
Stylist Trinny, 53, appeared on This Morning in a pair of white striped culottes from Urban Outfitters that she bought after admiring them on her 13-year-old daughter, Lyla Elichaoff.
</description>
<enclosure url="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/04/13/13/3F36FB3200000578-0-image-a-58_1492086235218.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="9078"/>
<pubDate>Thu, 13 Apr 2017 13:38:02 +0100</pubDate>
<guid>
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-4408430/Mothers-wear-clothes-daughters.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490
</guid>
<media:description/>
<media:thumbnail url="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/04/13/13/3F36FB3200000578-0-image-a-58_1492086235218.jpg" width="154" height="115"/>
<media:credit scheme="urn:ebu">Ken McKay/ITV/REX/Shutterstock</media:credit>
<media:content type="image/jpeg" url="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/04/13/13/3F36FB3200000578-0-image-a-58_1492086235218.jpg"/>
</item>
```

My code to loop through the rss feed items

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = textBox1.Text;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            String subject = item.Links.
            articletext.Text = subject;
        }
    }
```

I have tried 'item.links.tostring();' and 'item.link;' and neither seems to work, how can I get the RSS feed's links?

Comment: what you are getting in `reader`  and `feed` variable? note that the node in xml is `item` not `items` same for `links`

Comment: If I use Item.Link.ToString(); I get the following: System.ServiceModel.Syndication.NullNotAllowedCollection`1[System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationLink]

Comment: If you debug properly you can easily check what response you are getting. and what you need to write to get the values. Go step by step check for the values inspect them add to watch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access links like this:

```
foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
    string link = item.Links[0].Uri.ToString();
    string text = item.Summary.Text;
}
```